# Get ng-reapeat's $index in javascript (code behind)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can i get the actual value of `$index` from code behind?

My html is:

```
<div class="list-group nav nav-stacked">
    <a 
        ng-repeat="data in dbdata | orderBy:'heading' | filter:tocsearch"
        ng-click="jumpToManual(data.user_manual_id)"
        class="list-group-item"
        ng-class="{'active':data.user_manual_id===manualdata.page_id, 'selected': selectedIndex}">
        {{data.heading}}
    </a>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right" ng-click="nextManual(data.$index)" type="button">Next &rarr;</button>
```

The target is to achieve a button  outside the ng-repeat with the nextManual function in  which the $index of the ng-repeat is passed.

Comment: $index is available in the children scope, simply used it as a variable attached to the child scope. In the template and in the controller

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `$parent.$index` to ngClick function as a parameter:

```
<div class="list-group nav nav-stacked">
    <a ng-repeat="data in dbdata | orderBy:'heading' | filter:tocsearch" 
       ng-click="jumpToManual(data.user_manual_id, $parent.$index)" 
       class="list-group-item" 
       ng-class="{'active':data.user_manual_id===manualdata.page_id, 'selected': selectedIndex}">
       {{data.heading}}
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: fine, but what if my my button is outside the ng-repeat?

<div class="list-group nav nav-stacked">
    <a ng-repeat="data in dbdata | orderBy:'heading' | filter:tocsearch"
        ng-click="jumpToManual(data.user_manual_id)"
        class="list-group-item"
        ng-class="{'active':data.user_manual_id===manualdata.page_id, 'selected': selectedIndex}">
        {{data.heading}}
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4"><button class="btn btn-default pull-right" ng-click="nextManual(data.$index)" type="button">Next &rarr;</button></div>

Comment: @rzdesign Can you update your question then? Don't you have next button for each item in ngRepeat?

Comment: I dont have the next/prev button for each button.

Comment: @rzdesign Update the HTML in your question. It will be easier to understand.